# Laravel 5.4 removing mail field when reseting password

Tags: email, laravel-5.4, reset-password

I tried to know if there's a way to remove the email field when we reset password in Laravel (5.4). It's still a discussion in the [github forum](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15733)
so I want to know if anyone here has find a clean solution to do it.

In fact, it doesn't make sense to have mail in password reset:
[image]

Comment: Actually, there are 02 suggested solutions:
[1] by editing/hacking ResetPassword.php notification & reset.blade.php file as explained [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15733#issuecomment-330822049)
[2] or trying without editing vendor files according [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15733#issuecomment-355613513)

Answer (score 2):

Declare this function inside a helper file somewhere

```
function get_user_by_token($token){
    $records =  DB::table('password_resets')->get();
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        if (Hash::check($token, $record->token) ) {
           return $record->email;
        }
    }
}
```

Then Inside the reset.blade.php hide the from-group of the email and in the input email paste this !

```
value="{{ old('email') ?? get_user_by_token($token) }}"
```